# Using Froogaloop to pause Vimeo on click

Tags: vimeo, froogaloop

I have a video player on my site that has multiple videos all in a slider-type layout. There are thumbnails of each video underneath, and I need any playing video to pause if any of the thumbnails are clicked. I have the froogaloop.js in my head, and this code in my scripts.js file :
    (function(){

```
            // Listen for the ready event for any vimeo video players on the page
            var vimeoPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('iframe'),
                player;

            for (var i = 0, length = vimeoPlayers.length; i < length; i++) {
                player = vimeoPlayers[i];
                $f(player).addEvent('ready', ready);
            }

            /**
             * Utility function for adding an event. Handles the inconsistencies
             * between the W3C method for adding events (addEventListener) and
             * IE's (attachEvent).
             */
            function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
                if (element.addEventListener) {
                    element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
                }
                else {
                    element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Called once a vimeo player is loaded and ready to receive
             * commands. You can add events and make api calls only after this
             * function has been called.
             */
            function ready(player_id) {
                // Keep a reference to Froogaloop for this player
                var container = document.getElementById(player_id).parentNode.parentNode,
                    froogaloop = $f(player_id),
                    apiConsole = container.querySelector('.console .output');

                /**
                 * Prepends log messages to the example console for you to see.
                 */
                function apiLog(message) {
                    apiConsole.innerHTML = message + '\n' + apiConsole.innerHTML;
                }

                // Setup clear console button
                var clearBtn = container.querySelector('.console button');
                addEvent(clearBtn, 'click', function(e) {
                    apiConsole.innerHTML = '';
                }, false);

                apiLog(player_id + ' ready!');
            }
        })();
```

Then I have this for my thumbnails:

```
jQuery("a.switch-foto").click(function(){
    jQuery(".fotos").fadeOut();
    jQuery(".fotos").removeClass("first");
    jQuery('#see_'+this.id).delay(600).fadeIn();
    froogaloop.api('pause');
});
```

But when I test it on my site - it doesn't work - I get this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: froogaloop is not defined

can anyone help? Sorry I dont really understand Froogaloop.

Answer (score 4):

At first sight, in the click event the froogaloop.api call is not defined. In order to pause a video you should pass to Froogaloop the player to pause. Something like this:

```
Froogaloop( jQuery('iframe')[0] ).api('pause');
```

Note that Froogaloop has capital letter.
I'm stack with Froogaloop too. I hope this helps you.